# Is there a relation between quantum entanglement and inclusion-exclusion principle?

Tags: entanglement

If an entangled state is not simply the multiplication of each particle wave function:

$$ |\Psi_{ABC}\rangle \neq |\Psi_{A}\rangle|\Psi_{B}\rangle|\Psi_{C}\rangle $$

then can we apply the inclusion exclusion principle to calculate $|\Psi_{ABC}\rangle$? And how can this unknown relation help computation?

Edit: While in quantum mechanics we have measurement as an external interaction, internal interactions of an isolated (entangled) N-particle system is yet unknown. There is the Hohenberg-Kohn theorem but the analytical solution has not been found. My initial guess is that QM should obey the inclusion-exclusion principle for internal interactions (inside an entangled state) something like:

$$ H_{A\cup B \cup C} = H_A + H_B + H_C - H_{AB} - H_{BC} -H_{AC} + H_{A\cap B \cap C} $$

Where H can be Hamiltonian or another general property of particles. IE principle is $O(2^n)$ so it's a perfect candidate for both modelling QM and also for computation. Ideally with the combination of wavefunction superposition and $2^n$ interactions, an inclusive-exclusive computer could solve exponential problems. Back to the question, can we apply IE to calculate the entangled state?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE. It’s a potentially interesting perspective  but could you edit your question to expand on why you think there could be a relationship? For example with three qubits $A,B,C$?

Comment: there is something to be said about what I thought from the title the question was, but then reading the post itself I'm a bit confused. What do you mean exactly with "calculate $|\Psi_{ABC}\rangle$"? And in what form are you thinking about the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)? You then also involve the dynamics of the system, which then confuses me further as to what exactly you are asking

Comment: @glS By calculating $|\Psi_{ABC}\rangle$ I meant if we could find an analytic formula for it or not. For a general quantum interaction we may need a general formula but in the context of computation I think of inclusion-exclusion formula that exist in combinatorics. Don't be confused I only need to know where we can apply the inclusion-exclusion principle for describing entanglement, so please only answer to the title.

Comment: that's still not clear at all. Analytic formula for what, a generic tripartite state? "Calculate" $|\Psi_{ABC}\rangle$ from what information? You can always parametrise a generic state, if that's what you're asking, sure. But that has nothing to do with Hamiltonians, inclusion-exclusion formula, or anything of the sort. And again, what does the IE principle have to do with anything? It's a way to count elements in the union of sets; which sets are you thinking about here? Also, if the content of the post is asking something different than the title, please edit the post accordingly

Comment: @glS Thanks, I will edit it to be more accurate. I thought there could be a correspondence between a particle and a set. Would you write the generic tripartite state please?